# Cassandra does not compact shadowed rows for TWCS

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra table with default TTL. Unfortunately, the default TTL was too small, so now I want to update the default TTL, but also I need to update
all rows. Right now my table uses 80 GB of data. I am wondering how to perform this operation to not negatively impact performance.

For testing purposes, I adjusted a little bit configuration of my table:

```
AND compaction =  {'class' : 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy',
    'compaction_window_unit' : 'MINUTES',
    'compaction_window_size' : 10 ,
    'tombstone_compaction_interval': 60,
    'log_all': true }
AND default_time_to_live = 86400
AND gc_grace_seconds = 100
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I am using Time Window Compaction Strategy, compaction is executed every 10 minutes. To speed up all operations, I set `tombstone_compaction_interval` to 1 minute - so after one minute SSTable is taking into account for compaction. `gc_grace_seconds` is set to 100 seconds.

In my first scenario, I just overwrite every row without deleting it. As far as I understand, tombstones in that scenario are not created, I just shadow previously inserted rows.
So I perform the following steps:

1. write data
2. nodetool flush - to flush memtable to sstable
3. overwrite all rows
4. nodetool flush
5. Even after one hour both SStables exist

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 4.7M Jan 30 14:04 md-1-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 4.7M Jan 30 14:11 md-2-big-Data.db
```

Of course, If I execute `nodetool compact`, I will end up with one SStable with size 4.7MB, but I was expecting that compacting an old SSTable will be executed automatically, as it happens when in an SSTable there are many tombstones.
In the second scenario, I executed the same operations, but I explicitly removed every row before writing it again. The result was, the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 4.7M Jan 30 16:16 md-4-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 6.2M Jan 30 16:35 md-5-big-Data.db
```

So, SSTable was bigger, because it has to store information about tombstones and about new values. But again, SSTables were not compacted.

Can you explain to me, why automatic compaction was not executed? In this case old row, tombstone and new row can be replaced by just one entry that represents new row.

Answer (score 1):

First, `log_all` value of `true` should *not* be set in a production cluster for an indefinite period of time. You could test it out in lower environments and then remove it in the production cluster. I believe this is temporarily turned on for triaging purposes only. There are other red flags here in your case above, for example, setting `gc_grace_seconds` to `100 seconds`, you loose the opportunity/flexibility to recover during a catastrophic situation as you're compromising on the default hints generation and have to perform manual repairs, etc. You could read about why that's not a great idea in other SO questions.

First question we need to ask is if there is an opportunity to have an application downtime and then decide with other options.

If given a downtime window, I may work with the below procedure. Remember, there are multiple ways and this is just one of them.

1. Ensure that application(a) aren't accessing the cluster.
2. Issue a [DSBulk unload](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkSimpleUnload.html) operation to get the data exported out.
3. Truncate the table
4. Ensure you've the right table properties set (e.g. compaction settings, default ttl, etc.,).
5. Issue a [DSBulk load](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkSimpleLoad.html) operation by specifying the desired TTL value in seconds using [`--dsbulk.schema.queryTtl number_seconds`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/schemaOptions.html#schemaQueryTtl).
6. Perform your validation prior to opening the application(s) traffic back.

Other reading references:

- [TWCS how does it work and when to use it?](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html)
- [hinted-handoff demystified](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/03/21/hinted-handoff-gc-grace-demystified.html)

Comment: Values for `log_all`, `gc_grace_seconds` was modified on my local Cassandra installation to have better visibility and speed up testing. 

> First question we need to ask is if there is an opportunity to have an application downtime and then decide with other options.

Downtime is not an option in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the links, especially about TWCS:

> _TWCS is no fit for workload that perform deletes on non TTLed data. Consider that SSTables from different time windows will never be compacted together, so data inserted on day 1 and deleted on day 2 will have the tombstone and the shadowed cells living in different time windows. Unless a major compaction is performed (which shouldn’t), and while the deletion will seem effective when running queries, space will never be reclaimed on disk._

This means that the behaviour I observe is not surprising and it was implemented in that way.

Comment: The only one option that I see right now, is to overwrite every row and then run major compaction. Can you explain to me, if in this case, manual compaction can negatively impact my cluster - like increase query times? @Madhavan

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019137/why-is-forcing-major-compaction-on-a-table-not-ideal